# How to Convert Object to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to convert an object to an array of smaller, single-property objects in Javascript.
For example:

```
x={
    a: {a1:"a1", a2:"a2"},
    b: {b1:"b1", b2:"b2"},
    c: {c1:"c1", c2:"c2"}
}
```

converted to

```
y=[
    {a: {a1:"a1", a2:"a2"}},
    {b: {b1:"b1", b2:"b2"}},
    {c: {c1:"c1", c2:"c2"}}
]
```

I know this is possible with loops, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way. I'm using underscore/lo-dash if they help.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in way to do this. Just write a loop.

Comment: Do you want the keys to be in any particular order? I notice that they're alphabetical in your example, but the order of keys in an object is not guaranteed.

Comment: @PraveenKumar This isn't the same as that, because he wants an extra level of nesting added.

Comment: Do functions that perform implicit looping, like `.map()`, count as loops in your search for something more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for it.

```js
var x = { a: { a1: "a1", a2: "a2" }, b: { b1: "b1", b2: "b2" }, c: { c1: "c1", c2: "c2" } },
    y = Object.keys(x).map(function (k) {
        var o = {};
        o[k] = x[k];
        return o;
    });

console.log(y);
```

ES6 @[Nenad Vracar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4620771/nenad-vracar)

```js
var x = { a: { a1: "a1", a2: "a2" }, b: { b1: "b1", b2: "b2" }, c: { c1: "c1", c2: "c2" } },
    y = Object.keys(x).map(k => ({[k]: x[k]}));

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar pointed out, it does make more sense to use `map` (I left my `reduce` versions for posterity):

```
let arr = Object.keys(x).map(key => { [key]: x[key] });
```

You can use `reduce` to turn it into an array:

```
Object.keys(x).reduce(function(acc, key) {
   var tmp = {};
   tmp[key] = x[key];
   acc.push(tmp);
   return acc;
}, []);
```

And if ES6 is available, you can make it a bit more concise:

```
Object.keys(x).reduce((acc, key) => {
   acc.push({ [key]: x[key] });
   return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: Why `reduce` instead of `map`?

Comment: Eh, good call @Barmar; not sure why I went with reduce instead of map...it's early?

Comment: There seems to be a tendency for people to look for clever ways to use `reduce` when it's not really appropriate, it's one of my pet peeves.

Comment: @Barmar understandable, I always use reduce to turn arrays into objects, and I think my morning brain had me confusing the operation, updated my answer with map